# Gulp BrowserSync does not refresh

Tags: javascript, gulp

**Link to Github Repo: https://github.com/janschloss/boilerplate**

My problem is that only scss changes get recognized by BrowserSync in Gulp (no html or js or /img changes). I guess that is because scss changes are streamed directly. Weirdly I had one build which recognized html and img changes though I can't find that again.

Does someone see the mistake?

```
"use strict";

// Define packages

var gulp            = require('gulp'),
    sass            = require('gulp-sass'),
    clean           = require('gulp-clean'),
    sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    plumber         = require('gulp-plumber'),
    imagemin        = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    uglify          = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat          = require('gulp-concat'),
    strip           = require('gulp-strip-comments'),
    browserSync     = require('browser-sync');

// Define file paths

var scssSrc = 'src/scss/**/*.scss',
    jsSrc = 'src/js/*.js',
    htmlSrc = 'src/*.html',
    imgSrc = 'src/img/*';

// BrowserSync config

gulp.task('browserSyncInit', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./dist/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Concat scss files, compile compressed to css, prefix css, strip comments and create sourcemap

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(scssSrc)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.min.scss'))
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(strip.text())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

// Concatenate, uglify, strip comments and create sourcemap for js files

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(strip())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// Image optimization

gulp.task('img', function () {
    return gulp.src(imgSrc)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});

// Clean task

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('dist')
        .pipe(clean());
});

// Copy html

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    return gulp.src(htmlSrc)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

// Default Task

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'copy', 'sass', 'js', 'img', 'browserSyncInit'], function () {   //todo asynchronous
  gulp.watch(scssSrc, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(jsSrc, ['js']);
  gulp.watch(imgSrc, ['img']);
  gulp.watch(htmlSrc, ['copy']);
});
```

I think

```
gulp.watch('./dist/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

is the relevant line. Is there anything wrong with my path?

My relevant folder structure looks like:

```
gulpfile.js

src

dist
```

Changes are made in src and copied over to dist on runtime with gulp.

Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense to me that the scss only loads changes because it is the only task that has a call to browserSync.reload in it.  The others rely on the dist watch which isn't working for some reason. Try changing your watch on dist folder to ./dist/**/*.* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689334/gulp-globbing-how-to-watch-everything-below-directory

Comment: @DaveThomas Sadly that did not fix it.

Comment: Are you perchance using sublime text? A colleague of mine found an issue with the way it writes to disk not notifying a gulp watch

Comment: @DaveThomas I am using Atom :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain it. But when I remove your watch call from the browserSyncInit task and put it in the callback for the default task along side the other watches, everything works fine.

Relevant pieces of code:

```
// BrowserSync config

gulp.task('browserSyncInit', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'dist'
        }
    });

});


// Default Task

gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'copy', 'sass', 'js', 'img', 'browserSyncInit'], function () {   //todo asynchronous
  gulp.watch(scssSrc, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(jsSrc, ['js']);
  gulp.watch(imgSrc, ['img']);
  gulp.watch(htmlSrc, ['copy']);
    gulp.watch('./dist/**/*').on('change', function () {

        console.log("Watch hit");
        browserSync.reload();
    });
});
```

Is this ideal at all for your gulp file? I can kind of understand the thinking of having the watch originally triggered inside the other task.

Very weird thing I noticed; Sometimes the DIST watch would take and all the other watches wouldn't. As if there is a race condition happening on which ones get registered and the others get overwritten. When they were separated like you had them originally, either SRC watches worked or DIST watches worked. I could edit files in DIST directly when the DIST watch was working and trigger reload.

Keeping all the watches together in that CB function works for me using your github project.

I also noticed another unrelated issue. Rerunning your gulp file required me to rm -rf dist first other wise I got errors.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The reason for the rm -rf is that the gulp default task runs synchonous right now, need to change that (see the little //todo comment). Should have mentioned it, sorry.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thank you to you too for the experience! =) Have a good night, and all the best to you with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the glob: `'./dist/*'` - it will only watch the contents of `dist`. I think you want `'./dist/**/*'` to watch the folder and all subfolders.

Comment: Sadly that did not fix it.

Comment: Maybe `'dist/**/*'`?

Comment: :( no. Do you think it could be that the path I need is relative to the baseDir ?

Comment: Good point. Is dist folder in same directory as gulp file? That is where you are pointing with that path.

Comment: @DaveThomas The gulpfile, dist and src folders are on the same level.

Comment: The `baseDir` is the base of the app, i.e. where `index.html` lives. You're pointing `html` files to `dist/`, so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: The problem could be the js, html, and img globs... try `'src/js/**/*.js'`, etc.

Comment: @ic3b3rg I have uploaded a github repo, link: https://github.com/janschloss/boilerplate

Comment: @DaveThomas  I have uploaded a github repo, link: https://github.com/janschloss/boilerplate

Comment: @JanCastle beautiful  ;)

Comment: @JanCastle I can reproduce the same behaviour.  ./dist/**/* Does not work. I noticed you have it set to [*] instead in github project, that one wasn't working for me either.

Comment: @DaveThomas Yeah, I'm trying everything, getting desperate here :P Thanks for helping btw!