# Transform with Babel all the ES6 files in all the subfolders of subfolders into ES5 in each folder

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I have a folder with many subfolders and these subfolder have many subfolders. Is there a way to transform all the ES6 files into ES5 with a command from the root?

The approach I have is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('transform', function () {
return gulp.src('folder/**/**/**/**/**/*.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('folder/compiled'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
gulp.watch('folder/**/**/**/**/**/*.js', ['transform'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: In order to get as accurate as possible responses, do you have any script to share your current attempt or how you'd expect to implement this?

Comment: @alariva it has been edited the question with the approach I have.

Comment: Cool, so I guess that's not working and you want to know how to correctly transform all the files recursively? Looks like maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689334/gulp-globbing-how-to-watch-everything-below-directory) helps on this.

Comment: Yes, now works good, but now I have another problem. When it compiles, as it is watching, it creates a compiled folder inside a compile folder...and so on in every change @alariva

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp globbing- how to watch everything below directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689334/gulp-globbing-how-to-watch-everything-below-directory)

Comment: In order to keep clean and consistent content in StackOverflow, please proceed to open a new question that targets your specific problem. Provide as much and clear information to help others understand your problem and provide you with proper help.